# Combine three for loops to print data in one loop itself in proper format

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing a code wherein I wanted to print Product name, Product data and Product links all in proper format one by one. I used three for loops but the data is coming one below the other i.e. first all names are printed, then the prices and then the links are been printed. Below is the code I am using.

```
package com.browserst.test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BrowserSt {
    
    public static void wait(int secs) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(secs*1000);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Browser Gecko Driver files\\geckodriver.exe");
        wait(5);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("Driver launched");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("OnePlus 9");
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-submit-button")).click();
        List<WebElement> ad1=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='a-size-small a-color-base']"));
        ad1.get(0).click();
        wait(5);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='OnePlus']")).click();
        wait(5);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='128 GB']")).click();
        wait(3);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Featured']")).click();
        wait(3);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Price: Low to High']")).click();
        
        
        
        List<WebElement> ar1=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']"));
        List<WebElement> ar2=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='a-price-whole']"));
        List<WebElement> ar3=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/One')]"));
        
//  String arr1[]=new String[ar1.size()];
//  String arr2[]=new String[ar2.size()];
    //String arr3[]=new String[];
        
        List<String> arr1=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> arr2=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> arr3=new ArrayList<String>();
    
    
//  for(int i=0;i<ar1.size();i++) {
//      arr1.add(ar1.get(i).getText());
//  }
//  
//  
//
//  for(int i=0;i<ar2.size();i++) {
//      arr1.add(ar2.get(i).getText());
//  }
    
    
    for(int i=0,j=0,k=0;i<ar1.size()&&j<ar2.size()&&k<ar3.size();i++,j++,k++) {
        boolean b1=arr1.add(ar1.get(i).getText().toString());
        System.out.println("Product names"+":"+arr1.add(ar1.get(j).getText().toString()));
        System.out.println("Product price"+":"+arr2.add(ar2.get(j).getText().toString()));
        System.out.println("Product link"+":"+arr3.add(ar3.get(k).getAttribute("href").toString()));
    }
    
//  String namearray[]=new String[arr1.size()];
//  String pricearray[]=new String[arr2.size()];
//  System.out.println("Product Names,prices and links to product details page are as follows");
//  for(int i=0;i<arr1.size();i++) {
//      System.out.println(arr1.get(i).toString());
//  }
//  wait(5);
//  //System.out.println();
//  
//  //System.out.println("Display Prices");
//  
//  for(int i=0;i<arr2.size();i++) {
//      System.out.println(arr2.get(i).toString());
//  }
//  wait(5);
//  //System.out.println();
//  //System.out.println("Links to Product Details Page");
//  for(int i=0;i<arr3.size();i++) {
//      System.out.println(arr3.get(i).toString());
//  }
    wait(10);
    driver.quit();
        System.out.println("Driver closed");
    }

}
```

The output I was expecting is proper product names, prices and links but what it gave is boolean values. The output is as follows.

Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true
Product names:true
Product price:true
Product link:true

So I was not expecting this. Someone please help me to get rid of these boolean values and help me get that printed using single for loop in a proper manner. No one is answering. Is there no solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Because `add()` return boolean when adding an elment to a Collection

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<ar1.size();i++) {
    System.out.println("Product name:" + ar1.get(i).getText());
    System.out.println("Product price:" + ar2.get(i).getText());
    System.out.println("Product link:" + ar3.get(i).getText());
}
```

Comment: This should work, but you might want to write a check before entering the loop, to make sure all three Lists have the same length, or this will produce an IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

Comment: No. They don't have same length. The lengths are dynamic and hence I went for collection instead of array. I hope you are getting the point.

Comment: @RAVNMateus Yes, thanks for reminder, I saw the sample output first then decided not check length each of collection. Anyway, it's good to check 3 collections has the same length before reading the content.

Comment: No use of checking the length in the beginning. The product quantity is dynamically displayed and all the product prices are not displayed every time.

Comment: @PratikPathare yes, I understand. We're talking about 2 different things, so let it go.

Comment: Any other solution you have ?